# Stop background from adjusting to viewport size on a fixed width layout

Tags: html, css, background

My site is supposed to have a fixed width layout (Not responsive) with the background expanding the full width of the browser.

However when I shrink the browser the background gets cut off when it should stay at 100% full width. The same thing happens on an iphone and ipad, part of the background is cut off.

Website here: www.knockedupnowwhat.com

Im thinking that my css is wrong somewhere?

Thanks

Comment: It sounds like you're looking for the [viewport meta tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag)

Answer (score 1):

You need to setup min-width:1140px on all container elements that have width 100%. so for instance your footer should look like this

```
footer {
background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #474747;
min-width: 1140px;
width: 100%;}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the future, posting some of your code would be useful.

However the problem is because your div.container is set to 100% and it is your wrapper div. So when you resize the browser it will only be 100% of the browser, never wider. It's cutting off the backgrounds of it's child divs.